# XPath to get all text in element as one value, removing <wbr/> element

Tags: xpath

I need to locate the following "a" element in a HTML document.

```
<a>
304897: Failing Test Case "CALM501-I20140715-0705-
<wbr/>
Add CD to Cart"
</a>
```

I tried the following xpath for this purpose, but it is not finding the particular element possibly due to the existence of the "wbr" element in its text.

```
//a[substring-after(normalize-space(text()),': ')='Failing Test Case "CMAL501-I20140715-0705-Add CD to Cart"']
```

The above xpath tends to work when the "a" element does not contain a "wbr" element in its text.

Can someone please help me to find an appropriate xpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//a[substring-after(normalize-space(string(.)),': ')='Failing Test Case "CALM501-I20140715-0705- Add CD to Cart"']
```

Use XPath `string()` to get combined value of all text nodes within a tag. An example to make it clear, given input markup as you posted in question, this XPath :

```
substring-after(normalize-space(string(//a)),': ')
```

..will return :

```
Failing Test Case "CALM501-I20140715-0705- Add CD to Cart"
```

**UPDATE :**

Turned out that `normalize-space(string(.))` return the same value as `normalize-space(.)`, hence this will work as fine :

```
//a[substring-after(normalize-space(.),': ')='Failing Test Case "CALM501-I20140715-0705- Add CD to Cart"']
```

So it isn't a matter of using `string()` but a matter of not using `text()`, because the latter bring you each text node separately and may cause an undesired behavior as in your case here.

Comment: In fact `normalize-space(.)` returns the same as `normalize-space(string(.))` so the expression can be shortened further. But the key is: you should almost never use `text()`!

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks, I didn't fully aware of this before